# Entity Framework, Repository, Data Layer, 3 Layer

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, repository, data-layers, topdown

I'm trying to visualize a 3-layer design with Entity Framework.

If I have a Repository on top of the EF Context, are they *both* components of the Data Layer?

Or is the Repository the Data Layer itself, and EF something else?

I'll have a BLL that communicates with the repository or Data Layer (I have no clue..) and I'm trying to figure out how this all fits together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call a repository on top of EF a **Data Layer Abstraction**. I would not visualize it as a separate layer. The repository is the Data Layer.

Otherwise you could start to say that EF itself is a *Data Layer Abstraction* because it's an ORM supporting many database systems and is an implementation of the Repository and Unit of Work pattern itself. You would end up to say that you have a database as the Data Layer and a data layer abstraction in form of the ORM called EF and then a second-level abstraction in form of your custom repository on top of EF.

The layer which manages the access to the data storage in your application is the Data Layer - and that is your repository. EF and the database is just a detail of this layer, I'd say.